# Checking for null but getting error: null is not an object

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I have an if statement in my code, that checks if the displayName is null. If it is then it retries, as the user has to wait for a firebase function to create the user data, which then gets changed by the user. The render has to return a loading screen while the displayName gets changed from null. My only problem is that when I check if the displayName is null, I get the error:

> null is not an object (evaluating this.props.currentUser.displayName

Here is my code:

```
class MainPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            userDataFetched: false
        }

        this.checkUser = this.checkUser.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.checkUser()
    }

    checkUser() {
        if (this.props.currentUser.displayName !== null) {
            this.userDataFetched = true
            window.clearTimeout(this.checkUser)
            console.log("Ran checkUser(), displayName=", this.props.currentUser.displayName, ", userDataFetched=", this.userDataFetched)
        } else {
            window.clearTimeout(this.checkUser)
            window.setTimeout(this.checkUser, 500)
            console.log("Retrying checkUser(), displayName=", this.props.currentUser.displayName)
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.userDataFetched) {
            return 
        } else {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>Loading...</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to check the displayName without getting the error?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to read a property of `null` here:

```
if (this.props.currentUser.displayName !== null) {
```

You're probably passing `null` when a user isn't logged in, so you'll have to handle this case in your if statement.

```
if (this.props.currentUser && this.props.currentUser.displayName !== null) {
  // Your logic
}
```

Above will ensure that `currentUser` is not `null`, so you can safely check whether the `displayName` property is set or not.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the optional chaining syntax to get `if (this.props.currentUser?.displayName !== null) {`